# What is the upload bandwidth limit over WebRTC data channels?

Tags: networking, webrtc

What is the maximum of KB/s you can send and receive with WebRTC data channel. What is the maximum of send() call per second allowed. And what are the best ways to send reliable data over WebRTC data channels (what is being sent is exactly what is received)

Comment: The maximum will depend on how fast your computer can send the data, how fast the recipient can receive it, and on the network conditions in between. There's no inherent limit within the WebRTC specification as far as I know, and the practical answer is *it depends*.

Comment: Do you know how to force messages to be sent over TCP instead of UDP ?

Comment: You can't force SCTP to use TCP, it uses UDP per it's spec. ICE will at times tunnel a peers data channel through a TCP connection in cases where ICE/STUN cannot get UDP packets through a given NAT but this is not configurable and places a relay service between peers causing a dramatic cut in network performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the maximum of KB/s you can send and receive with WebRTC
>   datachannel.

It depends on your connection. There was a hard limit set in the SDP, Sharefest developers found a way to increase it, but it's gone for now.

> What is the maximum of send() call per second allowed.

You can call it anytime you want, but you have to make sure to don't fill the buffer too much, you can check it with the [bufferedAmount property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel/bufferedAmount), you can [read more](http://viblast.com/blog/2015/2/25/webrtc-bufferedamount) about it.

> And what are the best ways to send reliable data over WebRTC
>   datachannels (what is being sent is exactly what is received)

There was a `reliable` property for that, it is deprecated and have been replaced by these:

> - ordered
>
>   Indicates whether or not messages sent on the RTCDataChannel are required   to arrive at their destination in the same order in which they were sent [...]
> - maxPacketLifeTime
>
>   The maximum number of milliseconds that attempts to transfer a message may take in unreliable mode.
> - maxRetransmits
>
>   The maximum number of times the user agent should attempt to retransmit a message which fails the first time in unreliable mode.

Here's an example for a reliable mode:

```
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection();
var channel = pc.createDataChannel('dc', {
  ordered: true,
  maxPacketLifeTime: 1000,
  maxRetransmits: 5
});
```

You can read more about these properties [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createDataChannel).

Comment: One can use `maxPacketLifeTime` or `maxRetransmits`. But not both at the same time.

Comment: Where did you say that it's gone now? It's still there and respected by major browsers..

Comment: @jeffbRTC I was referring to the "way to increase it", sorry if I've done a typo here

Comment: @AxelIsouard "Sharefest developers found a way to increase it, but it's gone for now" is incorrect. Browsers still respect the property of SDP. It's in WebRTC spec. You can increase and Chrome will queue it behalf of you which is nice because you don't have to listen shitty events to resend!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on two issues, the network speeds of each connected peer as well as the WebRTC implementation of each peer. Each browser has different specs, but as a peer to peer web technology you will often have Firefox connecting with Chrome etc, and many will be using outdated browser versions with WebRTC stacks in differing states of maturity. These can be a substantial issues since the speed of p2p networking is typically limited to the speed of the slowest peers that your connected to.